# How to use KL divergence to compare two distributions?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, loss-functions, kullback-leibler, generative-models

I am trying to model the probability distribution of a multi-dimensional dataset where all the values are discrete. Suppose the training data (represented by T) is of the shape (m, n) where n is the number of features and m is the number of samples. I use a neural network to generate a dataset G which is also of shape (m, n).

I calculate the empirical $pmfs$ for each of the features separately: $P = (p_{i1}, p_{i2}, ... p_{in})$ representing the actual distribution and $Q = (q_{i1}, q_{i2}, ..., q_{in})$ representing the generated distribution. Here each $p_{i}$ and $q_{i}$ is multi-dimensional since each feature can take multiple categorical values. Finally, I am calculating the KLD as:

$KLD = \frac{1}{n} \times q_{i}log(\frac{q_{i}}{p_{i}})$

The logs and multiplication are done element-wise, since $p_{i}$ and $q_{i}$ are multi-dimensional.

While training, the objective is to minimize the above sum. Is the above calculation correct?

Another method would be to calculate the $P$ and $Q$ for the entire distribution together, but that seems like a bad idea since each feature can take a number of values, and the training sample size is pretty small (around 5,000 samples).

[How do I calculate KL-divergence between two multidimensional distributions?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/275033/how-do-i-calculate-kl-divergence-between-two-multidimensional-distributions) is a somewhat similar question but there was no clear answer on that thread.