# Transformation of discrete KL-Divergence in Continuous KL-Divergence possible?

Tags: normal-distribution, python, kullback-leibler, scipy

I Use Python and the following definition of KL-Divergence

```
def kl_divergence(p, q):
      return np.sum(np.where(p != 0, p * np.log(p / q), 0))
```

to calculate the divergence betweet two normal distributions:

```
x = np.linspace(norm.ppf(0.01, loc=0, scale=1), norm.ppf(0.99, loc=0, scale=1), 100)
a=norm.pdf(x, 0, 2)
b=norm.pdf(x, 2, 2)
kl_divergence(a, b)
```

The results depend on x and analytically, the result are wrong, because I used KL-Divergemnce for discrete distributions. I belief I could use these results for some practical purposes, but I need the real divergences. My question is, how can I implement KL-Divergence in python, such that it yields the analytically correct divergences? Does it work without integration to somehow transform the discrete results? If no, how can I integrate with numpy and scipy? I want to use it for the distribution that scipy has (normal, laplace,...) included.

Comment: Is it for specific distributions? If yes you could use closed form formulas of the KL that exists for the most common distribution including the one that scipy use.

Comment: No, I mean general.I did it with cloes form formulas for two normals. But already for Laplacian and Normal i am stuck with my math skills.

Comment: You must clarify your question! You use a formula for discrete distributions, on the empirical observations. So you calculate the KL divergence between two empirical distributions. It seems what you want is to **estimate**, not calculate, KL divergence. Then we need to know your model assumptions. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211175/kullback-leibler-divergence-for-two-samples/248657#248657  (maybe a dup)

Comment: How about estimating the KL by discretizing the pdfs by uniform sampling and then use your discrete KL formula?

Comment: Apprentice's comment sound like what i want or need to do. Can I do this somehow with numpy/scipy?

Comment: @kjetil: I want to calculate it, however I don't know how I can calculate Integrals with python and thought there might be some "trick" to approximate it with the discrete one. I try to improve my question.

Comment: As you mentioned, this is the wrong approach because KL divergence for continuous distributions requires integration. Solving the integral in closed form is the best approach if possible. Otherwise, you can compute integrals numerically. For example, see `scipy.integrate.quad()`. In this case, keep in mind that $D_{KL}(p \parallel q) = H(p,q) - H(p)$ (the difference of the cross entropy and the entropy). In some cases, an analytical expression may be available for $H(p)$, so only $H(p,q)$ need be computed numerically.

Comment: you're calculating on a finite grid but your distributions have an infinite support, so at the very least you should "normalize" by dividing by the sum over the finite support, to ensure that the integral does indeed integrate to 1. Something like `p /= np.sum(p)`