# estimation of KL-divergence of continuous distributions

Tags: distributions, sampling, kullback-leibler

Assume we have two independently sampled datasets, $X = \{x_{1}, \dots,  x_{n}\}$ and $Y = \{y_{1}, \dots,  y_{m}\}$ from continuous distributions $f$ and $g$. I aim to estimate the KL-divergence between $f$ and $g$, i.e $D_{KL}(f||g) = \int f(z)\log(\frac{f(z)}{g(z)})dz$.

The question: what would be a correct way to estimate $D_{KL}(f||g)$?

In the case of discrete distributions, the situation is very clear: we can just estimate the distributions by vectors of frequencies and then compute KL for these two vectors.

Comment: Have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211175/kullback-leibler-divergence-for-two-samples/248657#248657

Comment: Dear @kjetilbhalvorsen, thank you! Please, look at your answer there. I am afraid that you forgot to update your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an open problem in statistics and machine learning. Several methods to approximate the KL divergence have been proposed. For instance, take a look at the `FNN` R package:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/FNN/FNN.pdf

It miserably fails sometimes, but it works in simple cases and with large samples (for samples smaller than 100 it can behave erratically). For instance, consider the distance between a t distribution with $\nu =1,2,3, 100$ degrees of freedom and a normal distribution (R code taken from [this link](https://rpubs.com/FJRubio/DKLtn)).

## With $n=10,000$ samples

```
library(knitr)
library(FNN)

# Normalising constant
K <- function(d,nu) (gamma(0.5*(nu+d))/( gamma(0.5*nu)*sqrt((pi*nu)^d) ))

# Kullback Liebler divergence
DKLn <- function(nu){
  val1 <- -0.5*d*log(2*pi)  -0.5*d
  tempf <- Vectorize(function(t) exp(-0.5*t)*t^(0.5*d-1)*log(1+t/nu))
  int<- integrate(tempf,0,Inf,rel.tol = 1e-9)$value
  val2 <-  log(K(d,nu)) - 0.5*(nu+d)*(1/(gamma(0.5*d)*2^(0.5*d)))*int
  return(val1-val2)
}

# Kullback Liebler divergence: numerical integration 1-d
DKLn2 <- function(nu){
  tempf <- Vectorize(function(t) dnorm(t)*(dnorm(t,log=T) - dt(t,df=nu,log=T)))
  int<- integrate(tempf,-Inf,Inf,rel.tol = 1e-9)$value
  return(int)
}

# Kullback Leibler in one dimension
d=1 # dimension

DKLn(1)
X <- rt(10000, df = 1)
Y <- rnorm(10000)
plot(KL.divergence(Y, X, 100))

DKLn(2)
X <- rt(10000, df = 2)
Y <- rnorm(10000)
plot(KL.divergence(Y, X, 100))


DKLn(3)
X <- rt(10000, df = 3)
Y <- rnorm(10000)
plot(KL.divergence(Y, X, 100))

DKLn(100)
X <- rt(10000, df = 100)
Y <- rnorm(10000)
plot(KL.divergence(Y, X, 100))
```

## With $n=250$

```
library(knitr)
library(FNN)

# Normalising constant
K <- function(d,nu) (gamma(0.5*(nu+d))/( gamma(0.5*nu)*sqrt((pi*nu)^d) ))

# Kullback Liebler divergence
DKLn <- function(nu){
  val1 <- -0.5*d*log(2*pi)  -0.5*d
  tempf <- Vectorize(function(t) exp(-0.5*t)*t^(0.5*d-1)*log(1+t/nu))
  int<- integrate(tempf,0,Inf,rel.tol = 1e-9)$value
  val2 <-  log(K(d,nu)) - 0.5*(nu+d)*(1/(gamma(0.5*d)*2^(0.5*d)))*int
  return(val1-val2)
}

# Kullback Liebler divergence: numerical integration 1-d
DKLn2 <- function(nu){
  tempf <- Vectorize(function(t) dnorm(t)*(dnorm(t,log=T) - dt(t,df=nu,log=T)))
  int<- integrate(tempf,-Inf,Inf,rel.tol = 1e-9)$value
  return(int)
}

# Kullback Leibler in one dimension
d=1 # dimension

DKLn(1)
X <- rt(250, df = 1)
Y <- rnorm(250)
plot(KL.divergence(Y, X, 100))

DKLn(2)
X <- rt(250, df = 2)
Y <- rnorm(250)
plot(KL.divergence(Y, X, 100))


DKLn(3)
X <- rt(250, df = 3)
Y <- rnorm(250)
plot(KL.divergence(Y, X, 100))


DKLn(100)
X <- rt(250, df = 100)
Y <- rnorm(250)
plot(KL.divergence(Y, X, 100))
```